# Any MySQL command to duplicate rows except for auto_increment column?

Tags: mysql, duplicates, row

I have been looking for a way to duplicate a row, and insert it back to the table, but with a different id value (whose type is auto increment).

I could do this by specifying every column manually, but as there are many columns, and as the columns can be added or removed in the future, I want to use some easy query to do this without having to specify every column name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table SELECT * FROM source_table WHERE ...; 
ALTER TABLE temp_table DROP COLUMN column_with_auto_increment;
INSERT INTO source_table SELECT * from temp_table; DROP TABLE temp_table;
```

Comment: Well, it looks good idea... Any way though, just to use one line command? Also using many temporary table is not suggested to use often as I remember.... I think this answer gives me an idea any way.

Comment: I afraid there is no other way as you like to not to list all possible fields.

Comment: INSERT results in the error `column count doesn't match value count at row 1`
Needs to be updated to this:
`INSERT INTO source_table SELECT NULL, tt.* from temp_table tt;`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
INSERT INTO new_table (attr1, attr2, attr3) SELECT oldatr1, oldatr2, oldatr3 FROM old_table WHERE <the filter you want>
```

It also may work if new_table and old_table are the same.

Comment: No.... As I have stated in the question, I know this way. What I m looking for is the way to do without having to specify every columns.

Comment: Anyway, I do not love to see those who tried to answer get minus useful value, so just did +1